# iPhone 4 play animation when a view is presented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

I want to position buttons within my view in a circle around a fixed point. I can do this with :

```
 button.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(offsetX/button.frame.size.width, offsetY/button.frame.size.height);

button.transform = [self calculateLabelPositionFromFixedPointWithOffsetClockwiseInDegrees:commonAngleRatio*startSpacing*spacingRatio++];
```

Where the calculateLabelPositionFromFixedPointWithOffsetClockwiseInDegrees:angleInDegrees is a function that I wrote to give me CGAfflineTransformMakeRotation .

I would like the buttons to **animate "orbiting" into the correct position when the view is presented.** I tried putting a timer that will call animation into "viewWillAppear", but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: I'm subclassing a UIViewController twice:

```
@interface HomeScreenAbstractParentController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, ContextActionDelegate, RemoteControlDelegate> {...}
```

and

```
@interface AnimatedController : HomeScreenAbstractParentController
{}
```

**Within the AnimatedController the following methods do not get called**. I have the AnimatedController's view added to the back of the homeScreenController (as in Weather app), and when a user presses a button, the view flips to it's backside. The backside should animate controls when this is done.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self animateControls:nil];


}
```

At which point in the lifecycle of the app above would I schedule the timer to animate buttons into positions? Is it when I flip the view over?

Comment: Why not use a UIView animation in viewDidAppear method ?

Answer (score 0):

in your viewController :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1]; //amount of seconds animation should run
button.transform = [self calculateLabelPositionFromFixedPointWithOffsetClockwiseInDegrees:commonAngleRatio*startSpacing*spacingRatio++];
[UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Comment: I would recommend using block style animations rather than -begin/-commit

Comment: Neither viewDidAppear nor viewWillAppear get called for my code. ViewDidLoad gets called once

Comment: viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear always get called when you present your viewControler's view property. If they are not getting called you are not presenting the view property correctly.